# How To add onError in Echo?

Tags: php, javascript

i just have a php script that show my slideshow image, i make it dynamic so the slideshow must match the image in folder to database before display it, when the database is empty or the image is not found, it just display an error message, i just want to add onError to anticipate that but i cant do it, can anyone help me???
here's the code

```
echo "<img src='".'slideshows/'.$rec2->image."'  title='".$rec2->name."' alt='".$rec2->description."' />";
```

i want to make it like

```
echo "<img src='".'slideshows/'.$rec->image."'  title='".$rec->name."' alt='".$rec->description."' onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='error.png'; this.onclick=null;" />";
```

but the onError didn't work, help me please...
sorry for my bad language...

Comment: Change `onError="...` to `onError=\"...`

Comment: i already try it, but still didn't work...

Comment: what does "didn't work" mean?

Comment: @MuhammadFahmy Check the generated output to see what's wrong.

Comment: @james it still show the error message, what i try to do is if the image is not found either in the directory or in the database, the slideshow didn't show the error message, but show image "error.png"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo sprintf(
  '<img src="slideshows/%s" title="%s" alt="%s" onError="%s" />', 
  $rec->image,
  $rec->name,
  $rec->description,
  "this.onerror=null;this.src='error.png'; this.onclick=null;"
);
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
echo "<img src='".'slideshows/'.$rec->image."'  title='".$rec->name."' alt='".$rec->description."' onError=\"this.onError=null;this.src='error.png'; this.onclick=null;\" />";
```

Comment: if the image isn't exist either in directory or database, it show this notice:
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\APKBx2\slideshows\index.php on line 154

Comment: then change `$rec->image` to `(isset($rec->image) && !empty($rec->image))?$rec->image:''`

Comment: with your script, if the image is exist, it didn't show the image but show the image name...